# alternative to reshape or colon in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I want to reduce a two dimensional matrix to row vector.

But using `reshape` with large matrices is really slow. The other alternative is to use `colon`, but i want matrix's transpose to be colon and not the matrix itself.

e.g.

```
A=magic(3)

A =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
```

`A(:)` will stack up all the columns one by one. but i am looking for something like this:

```
AA=A(2:3,:)';
```

and then reshape or colon AA instead of A.

The issue is i dont want to define additional variable like `AA`.

Is there anyway to reduce dimension of two dimensional matrix without `reshape`?

Comment: So why not just use `A(2:3,:)'` (or `A(2:end,:).'`) without assigning it to a variable?

Comment: I suspect it's not the `reshape` that takes time, but the need to copy the reshaped matrix into a different memory location.

Comment: @LuisMendo, I guess because the OP wants it as a one-dimensional array in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the additional variable by linear indexing. For your example:

```
A([2 5 8 3 6 9])
```

which gives

```
3  5  7  4  9  2
```

What's happening here is that you treat `A` as if it was already transformed into a vector, and the elements of this one-dimensional array are accessed through indices 1 through 9. Using the colon is a special case of linear indexing, `A(:)` is the same as `A(1 : end)`.

Figuring out the right linear indices can be tricky, but [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) can help with that.

It is possible that this slightly speeds up the code, mainly because (as [@Shai wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646369/alternative-to-reshape-or-colon-in-matlab#comment43711237_27646369)) you avoid writing data to an intermediate variable. I wouldn't expect too much, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [subsref](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html). For your example, you could use it as follows:

```
subsref(A',struct('type','()','subs',{{2:3,':'}}))
```

Update: I misunderstood the original question; I thought the OP wanted to select rows from 2:3 from the transposed A matrix keeping the columns as is. I will keep the previous answer in case it could be useful to others.

I think he/she could use the following to slice and flatten a matrix:

```
subsref(A(2:3,:)', struct('type','()','subs',{{':'}}))
```

This would give as output:

[3 5 7 4 9 2]'